# Flutter scoped_model not find when try to access with Navigator page

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using flutter scoped_model, When we try to access ScopedModel from child Widget which able to access without error.

But same code was not working with when i try to access it from Widget which load using Navigator.push, it gives error Error: Could not find the correct ScopedModel.

PageModel declare at top page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class PageModel extends Model {
    String title;

    static PageModel of(BuildContext context) =>
        ScopedModel.of<PageModel>(context);

    loadTitle() {
      title = 'Old Title ';
    }

    updateTitle() {
      title = 'New Title';
      notifyListeners();
    }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final PageModel model = PageModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<PageModel>(
      model: model,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        body: HomePageBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePageBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageBodyState createState() => _HomePageBodyState();
}

class _HomePageBodyState extends State<HomePageBody> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    PageModel.of(context).loadTitle();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<PageModel>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, child, PageModel model) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(model.title),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Edit'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => DetailPage(), fullscreenDialog: true),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Page'),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Update'),
        onPressed: () {
          PageModel.of(context).updateTitle();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

From DetailPage when we call PageModel.of(context).updateTitle(); following error coming,

```
/flutter (26710): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (26710): The following ScopedModelError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (26710): Error: Could not find the correct ScopedModel.
I/flutter (26710):     
I/flutter (26710): To fix, please:
I/flutter (26710):           
I/flutter (26710):   * Provide types to ScopedModel<MyModel>
I/flutter (26710):   * Provide types to ScopedModelDescendant<MyModel> 
I/flutter (26710):   * Provide types to ScopedModel.of<MyModel>() 
I/flutter (26710):   * Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_model.dart';
I/flutter (26710):   
I/flutter (26710): If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at:
I/flutter (26710): https://github.com/brianegan/scoped_model/issues/new
```

Answer (score 0):

What you’re doing is trying to find a `PageModel` of that context which there is none, since you haven’t created any for that specific widget context.

What you want to wrap your `RaisedButton` in a `ScopedModelDescendant<PageModel>` and update your model by using the `model.updateTitle()` instead. 
That will look for the closest PageModel ancestor in the tree.